# Add Expires headers Plesk

Tags: .htaccess, expires-header

My website gets Add Expires headers error from pingdom tools. I searched and found solution adding the codes below to .htaccess file.

`<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>`

but still I am getting same error. 
In plesk I found apache & nginx settings. Changed Expires settings but doesn't solved problem. What else can I do? Thanks [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_expires was disabled on apache. I activated it and worked.